# NetLogo - Display value of a turtle to monitor

Tags: netlogo

I am creating two agents which are of breed players.

```
breed [players player]
```

The players will need to have certain attributes therefore I have used players-own

```
players-own 
[
   lives
   health
   score
]
```

I have then created the two players and set the values for the attributes.

```
create-players 2

  ask player 0
  [
    set lives 3
    set health 100
    set score 0
  ]

  ask player 1
  [
    set lives 5
    set health 100
    set score 0

  ]
```

The part I am struggling to work out is how can I display the value of player 0's lives in one monitor and the value of player 1's lives in another monitor.

Any help on this would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put this code in one monitor:

```
[lives] of player 0
```

and this code in another:

```
[lives] of player 1
```